# How do I get the source code from the active editor?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I am writing my first vscode language extension and want to  load an array with the lines of my source code.   How can I get the source code of the active editor? I am creating a webview and want to manipulate a copy of the source code in the webview.

Shouldn’t this be obtained in the VScode language api?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the [TextDocument object](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TextDocument) in the VScode API, it provides a method called `.getText()` where given a range as input it returns the appropriate range of source code lines as text.

You can derive said object from the current active text editor in it's `.document` property or if you want to trigger on each document change you may use the following:

```js
    vscode.workspace.onDidChangeTextDocument(function (event) {
        let filename = event.document.fileName;
        let text = event.document.getText();
    });
```